# Remapping `v` in netrw/calling NetrwSplit(5) directly

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings, vimscript, functions, netrw

So I've created some helper functions to help work around netrw. They are some keybind simplifications that help with things like window/cursor management when opening files, where to open them, handing marked files, closing netrw when done etc.

I map them with the following in my vimrc:

```
augroup NetrwGroup
    autocmd!
    autocmd filetype netrw call NetrwMapping()
augroup END
```

```
function! NetrwMapping()
    setl bufhidden=wipe | setl modifiable
    nmap <buffer>x mf
    nmap <buffer>. cd
    nmap <buffer>C :NetrwTouch<CR>
    nmap <buffer>D :NetrwDelete<CR>
    nmap <buffer>h o
    nmap <silent> <buffer>T :call NetrwOpenInTabs()<CR>
    nmap <silent> <buffer>W :call NetrwOpenInWindows()<CR>
    nmap <silent> <buffer>B :call NetrwOpenInBuffers()<CR>
    " remap refresh to <c-r>, to free up <c-l>, so that it doesn't overwrite my window navigation mapping
    nunmap <buffer><C-r>
    nmap <buffer><C-r> <Plug>NetrwRefresh
    nmap <buffer><C-l> <C-w><Right>
endfunction
```

Now, what I'm trying to add is an alternate to `normal v` mapping. I know that normally `v` is mapped to `<SNR>76_NetrwSplit(5)<CR>)`. I'd like to be able to call that in my function and then do some additional things. So the mapping would be:

```
nmap <buffer>v :call NetrwOpenVirtSplit()<CR>
```

and a simple example of my function:

```
function! NetrwOpenVirtSplit()
    normal v
    " some other stuff
    " move the cursor
    " close netrw etc.
endfunction
```

Pressing `v` in netrw got me this:
[image: NetrwOpenVirtSplit too recursive]

So if that's an easy fix, I'd like to do that and go about my life.

Alternatively, and more complicatedly, I've looked into calling `<SNR>76_NetrwSplit(5)` directly, but I can't quite figure out the name spacing situation. This worked for example:

```
nmap <buffer>v :call <SNR>76_NetrwSplit(5)<CR>
```

But I know that the `<SNR>76_` part depends on the script ordering and is subject to change and could break etc. I've tried to dynamically compute it via the `s:SID()` function mentioned in the `:h <SID>` help but don't know where to put it or how to use it. Plus, I can't really easily add additional functionality to that in an easy way like I do with the other mappings.

Note: regarding namespacing, all the above mappings/function definitions are in my vimrc and `<SID>NetrwSplit()` is in `autoload/netrw`

Comment: As a rule of thumb always use non recursive version of the `map` command unless you know what you are doing so here try to make your mapping `nnoremap <buffer>v :call NetrwOpenVirtSplit()<CR>`, and as a second rule of thumb when in a script always force `normal` not to follow your mapping so in your function use `normal! v`. I think doing so has good chances to fix your recursive call.

Comment: That is my understanding for `nnoremap` as well. However, for mapping netrw commands, only `nmap` seems to have any effect at all. And `normal! v` did stop the recursive descent, however it ended up only activating visual mode; it didn't run the normal netrw command for `v` unfortunately.

Comment: I'm I see where is the issue. I think you have two options: 1) you don't use `v` in your mapping but `V` and this way the mapping is not recursive anymore or 2) in `NetrwOpenVirtSplit()` you replace `normal v` by a call to `NetrwSplit` or to your own code which will get the file under the cursor and open it in a split. I'll try to make the second option work if I have time today :)

Answer (score 1):

First let's understand what is the problem with your current code:

You need to use `normal v` in your `NetrwOpenVirtSplit()` function because that is how netrw opens a split. But as you have mapped `v` with a recursive mapping, you recursively call your function infinitely.

About calling `NetrwSplit()` directly from your mapping, I could be wrong but as this is a private function of the netrw plugin I don't think you can use it in a mapping defined outside of the plugin. This is because this local function feature was *made* to create private functions not callable by other scripts.

---

So we have several solutions:

**The first one is my favorite:** you keep everything as it is currently but you use another key in your mapping e.g `V` (`nmap <buffer> V :call NetrwOpenVirtSplit()<CR>`) this way you don't map an already used key and you don't have any recursion issues anymore.

**The second one is a bit more complex but based on my tests it seems to be working:**
Instead of using `normal v` in your function, you can reimplement the split opening by yourself with `execute 'vsplit ' . expand('<cfile>')`.

However this will not work in all situations because `expand('<cfile>')` will return only the filename in the netrw window and not its complete path so if you are exploring a directory which is not the current one you will open new files in the current directory (and of course they will be empty).

To fix that you can use `let g:netrw_keepdir= 0` to keep the current directory synced with your netrw browsing but this may have other undesired side effects.

If you are fine with that, the solution could be like this:

```
let g:netrw_keepdir= 0

augroup NetrwGroup
    autocmd!
    autocmd filetype netrw call NetrwMapping()
augroup END

function! NetrwMapping()
    nnoremap <buffer> v :call NetrwOpenVirtSplit()<CR>
endfunction

function! NetrwOpenVirtSplit()
    execute 'vsplit ' . expand('<cfile>')
    norm! 5j
endfunction
```

---

As a side note I really recommend that you get rid of your `NetrwGroup` autocommand group and `NetrwMapping()` function because all you are doing here is reimplementing something Vim is already doing.

Instead you should just create the file `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/netrw.vim`. In this file put only the content of your `NetrwMapping()` function.

Your new ftplugin file will be source when the filetype of a buffer is set to `netrw` (i.e. when you open Netrw) and you don't have to bloat your config with one more autocommand group.

[Here](https://vimways.org/2018/from-vimrc-to-vim/) is an amazing resource to help you doing this migration.